# Web Query missing css elements in the table

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-web-query, excelquery

I using a web query on the NCSL Excuse Absentee Voting Table (https://www.ncsl.org/elections-and-campaigns/table-2-excuses-to-vote-absentee). The table uses this element to mark cells that I would like to show as true:

```
<td>
     <ul>
          <li>::before
          &nbsp;</li>
     </ul>
</td>
```

When I query this I cannot get it to read those cells as having anything in them. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work. Replaces the bullet with XXX before processing

```
let Source = Web.Contents("https://www.ncsl.org/elections-and-campaigns/table-2-excuses-to-vote-absentee"),
Source1= Text.Combine(Lines.FromBinary(Source, null, null, 65001)),
Source2=Text.Replace(Source1,"<ul><li>&nbsp;</li></ul>","XXX"),
Source3=Web.Page(Source2){0}[Data]
in Source3
```

[image]

[image]